# Unable to initialize big matrices in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to initialize a two-dimensional array and then filling it up gradually. However whenever I try to initialize it, it gives Out of Memory error.

```
D = zeros(1000000, 1000000);
```

Is there any way to resolve the error and get a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that an array of this size would take almost 8TB of ram. If you want an array this big where almost all of the elements are `0`, you can use `spzeros(1000000, 1000000)` (defined in `SparseArrays`).

Comment: Actually I will fill it up with floats but I think this solution works. How did you measured ram required ?

Comment: 1000000*1000000 elements times 8 bytes per element.